# looping filenames in python

Tags: python, loops, filenames

I have few hundred bigfiles(based on line nos.).
I am trying to write a code using a loop. 
First the loop reads the bigfile in the folder,
second it will make a folder of the same filename it is reading
and lastly it will slice the file in the same folder created.
This loop should iterate over all the bigfiles present in the folder.
My code is as follow:

```
import glob
import os
os.chdir("/test code/")
lines_per_file = 106
sf = None
for file in glob.glob("*.TAB"):
    with open(file) as bigfile:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(bigfile):
            if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
                if sf:
                    sf.close()
                    sf_filename = '/test code/201511_sst/sf_{}.txt'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
                    sf = open(sf_filename, "w")
                    sf.write(line)
                    if sf:
                        sf.close()
```

I am getting the output as follow:

```
In [35]: runfile('/test code/file_loop_16Jan.py', wdir='/test code')
In [36]:
```

I need a little guidance in looping the files so that I can achieve it. I think no error means I am missing something !!
Please anyone can help me out !

Comment: Is there anything being written to the `*.txt` output files?

Comment: you set `sf = None` and do not modify it between there and the `if sf` line, so the final few lines will never be called.

Comment: First time through the loop, is `sf` true or false?

Comment: 1) Yes the bigfile has to be split and put in the sf_{} files after every 106 lines from bigfile.

Comment: 2) I want to loop all the bigfiles at once, as I mentioned, and split it. the new files (sf_{} named) will be kept in the folder of the name of the bigfile. that loop i am struggling ! Oops !

Answer (score 2):

`sf` is set to `None` at start so you never enter in the `if sf` loop: no output file is ever written anywhere.

Besides, when you close the file, you have to set `sf` to `None` again or you'll get "operation on closed file" when closing again.

But that won't do what you want. You want to split the file so do this:

```
        if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
            # new file, close previous file if any
            if sf:
                sf.close()
            # open new file
            sf_filename = '/test code/201511_sst/sf_{}.txt'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
            sf = open(sf_filename, "w")
        # write the line in the current handler
        sf.write(line)
```

- the first `if` is encountered at start: good. Since `sf` is `None` it doesn't call `close` (for the best)
- it then opens the file with the new filename
- now the line is written in the new file handle (you have to write one line at each iteration, not only when the modulo matches)

On next iterations, when the modulo matches, the previous file is closed, and a new handle is created with a new filename.

Don't forget to close the last file handle when exiting the loop:

```
if sf:
    sf.close()
```

I haven't tested it but the logic is here. Comment if you have subsequent issues I'll edit my post.

Aside: another problem is that if there are more than 1 big `*.TAB` file, the split file will be overwritten. To avoid that, I would add the input file basename in the output file for instance (`lineno` is reset in each loop):

```
sf_filename = '/test code/201511_sst/{}_sf_{}.txt'.format(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]),lineno + lines_per_file)
```

you can do that by storing the end `lineno` too and compute a line offset. It's up to you

Answer (score 0):

Since You're already using with statement for reading files, you can also use the same for writing into files, so that way, you  don't need to close the file object explicitly. see these links.

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

You can simply do this:

```
with open(file,"w") as sf:
    // read/write file content and do your stuff here
```

Comment: even after modification, but yields nothing ! I am stuck searching alternative !